# Failed to update Wine in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, wine

I am new to Ubuntu, I managed to install wine/wineHQ in order for running Roblox games for my kid. Recently I upgraded to 22.04 and
I've noticed that Wine/WineHQ is not yet ready for Ubuntu 22.04.
When trying to run "sudo apt update" & "sudo apt upgrade -y", I'm getting the following error:

`GPG error: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1~~~~~~~~`

Can anyone help me to understand and how to solve this ?

Any solution sugested didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix the GPG error "NO\_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

Comment: Please don't post images of text.

Answer (score -1):

I have found the following link which explain the issue:
[apt-secure - Archive authentication support for APT](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/apt-secure.8.en.html)